# Closing app manually and evoke method? [JavaFX]

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

In a booking system I'm making for an assignment, the application will create a ticket during the process which will carry relevant information for the final tickets. In the end, when customer chooses the required amount of tickets, it will take information from this temporary ticket and delete it. However, if you manually choose to close the program during the process, it will not delete this ticket and it will stay on the database.

Is there any way to evoke a method when closing the program manually?

Answer (score 1):

Override the stop() method in your Application class

```
public class MyApp extends Application
    @Override
     public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
         // your usual code here
     }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
         // your shutdown code here
     }
}
```